# Get ReadStream from Firebase Storage and pass into Openai API

Tags: javascript, next.js, firebase-storage, firebase-admin, openai-api

I am trying to download an image from firebase storage and pass it into an openai endpoint

currently, my code looks like this

```
const fileStorage = await getStorageAdmin(uid, "/sample.png");
  const file = fileStorage.createReadStream();

  const maskStorage = await getStorageAdmin(uid, "/mask.png");
  const mask = maskStorage.createReadStream();

 const res = await openai.createImageEdit(
      file,
      prompt,
      mask,
      1,
      "512x512",
      "url"
  ).catch((e) => {
      console.log("ERROR: " + e)
  })
```

But running this code results in a Bad Request (status code: 400).

When I tried reading the files from the harddisk, it worked without a problem

```
const file = fs.createReadStream("./images/anna.png");
  const mask = fs.createReadStream("./images/mask.png");

  const res = await openai.createImageEdit(
      file,
      prompt,
      mask,
      1,
      "512x512",
      "url"
  ).catch((e) => {
      console.log("ERROR: " + e)
  })
```

This means, the api request is fine but there must be a problem with reading from the firebase storage, since that is the only difference but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
I don't know what the difference between using fs.createReadStream() and firebase-admin's file.createReadStream is. I thought both methods should return the image contents but one is working and the other doesn't.

The getStorageAdmin function just returns the reference to the file I want to download.

```
export const getStorageAdmin = async (uid:string, imagepath:string) =>{
    return await getStorage().bucket().file(uid+imagepath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the firebase.createReadStream() function is an async function.

So it would be:

```
const fileStorage = await getStorageAdmin(uid, "/sample.png");
const file = await fileStorage.createReadStream();
```

Can you show the function for getStorageAdmin()?

Comment: I already tried that but without luck... I updated my question to include the getStorageAdmin function. Hope it helps